# Exploding a dataframe based on column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, explode

I have a Pandas dataframe that looks like this:

| Location | Number | Position |
| --- | --- | --- |
| New York | 111 | 1 through 12 |
| Dallas | 222 | 1 through 12 |
| San Francisco | 333 | 1 through 4 |

I would like to basically **explode** the dataframe based on the **Position** column so that the output looks like this:

| Location | Number | Position |
| --- | --- | --- |
| New York | 111 | 1 |
| New York | 111 | 2 |
| New York | 111 | 3 |
| New York | 111 | 4 |
| New York | 111 | 5 |
| New York | 111 | 6 |
| New York | 111 | 7 |
| New York | 111 | 8 |
| New York | 111 | 9 |
| New York | 111 | 10 |
| New York | 111 | 11 |
| New York | 111 | 12 |
| Dallas | 222 | etc. etc. |

I would like to do this for every instance of **Location** and **Number** based on what the values in **Position** are.

Is there a quick and easy way to do this??

Comment: Is position a string like you have showed?

Answer (score 1):

One option using `explode`:

```
out = (df
 .assign(Position=[range(a, b+1) for x in df['Position']
                   for a,b in [map(int, x.split(' through '))]])
 .explode('Position')
)
```

Another approach using reindexing:

```
df2 = df['Position'].str.extract('(\d+) through (\d+)').astype(int)
#    0   1
# 0  1  12
# 1  1  12
# 2  1   4

rep = df2[1].sub(df2[0]).add(1)

out = (df
 .loc[df.index.repeat(rep)]
 .assign(Position=lambda d: d.groupby(level=0).cumcount().add(df2[0]))
)
```

output:

```
        Location  Number  Position
0       New York     111         1
0       New York     111         2
0       New York     111         3
0       New York     111         4
0       New York     111         5
0       New York     111         6
0       New York     111         7
0       New York     111         8
0       New York     111         9
0       New York     111        10
0       New York     111        11
0       New York     111        12
1         Dallas     222         1
1         Dallas     222         2
1         Dallas     222         3
1         Dallas     222         4
1         Dallas     222         5
1         Dallas     222         6
1         Dallas     222         7
1         Dallas     222         8
1         Dallas     222         9
1         Dallas     222        10
1         Dallas     222        11
1         Dallas     222        12
2  San Francisco     333         1
2  San Francisco     333         2
2  San Francisco     333         3
2  San Francisco     333         4
```

Comment: Try to run `[x.split(' through ') for x in df['Position']]` ensure this always yields 2 numbers (as string)

Comment: And what about the second approach?